# Can you make an eeg chart with highchart?

Tags: highcharts

We are going to buy a high chart.

We are going to implement the medical chart eeg chart on the web.

Can I implement the shape of an eeg chart with a high chart?

The EEG chart shows that the X axis is time and the Y axis
It has 19 channels with individual ranges.

https://www.researchgate.net/figure/Case-6-EEG-in-a-38-year-old-woman-with-refractory-complex-partial-seizures-and-left_fig3_233806823

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using Highcharts, you can create as many axes as you need. I have prepared a simple example with multiple yAxes and different ranges:

```
var series = [],
  data,
  seriesCount = 20,
  pointsCount = 100,
  axisTop = 50,
  range,
  axisHeight = 1100 / seriesCount,
  yAxis = [];

for (var i = 0; i < seriesCount; i++) {
  range = Math.round(Math.random() * 100);
  data = [];
  for (var j = 0; j < pointsCount; j++) {
    data.push(Math.floor(Math.random() * range));
  }
  series.push({
    data: data,
    yAxis: i
  });
  yAxis.push({
    title: {
      text: ''
    },
    height: axisHeight,
    top: axisTop,
    offset: 0
  });

  axisTop += axisHeight + 12.5
}

Highcharts.chart('container', {
  chart: {
    height: 1500
  },
  series: series,
  yAxis: yAxis
});
```

Live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/425xctvw/

Comment: please one more question , Can I draw an annotation beyond the range of the individual y-axis?

Comment: Yes, you can add annotations to your chart in different ways. One of them is to assign annotations to the axes, example: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/5xmrvcko/. API: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/annotations

Answer (score 1):

You can try for synchronized charts where x axis can be common across all the graphs.

https://www.highcharts.com/demo/synchronized-charts

Reference Code: https://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/synchronized-charts/

```js
/*
The purpose of this demo is to demonstrate how multiple charts on the same page
can be linked through DOM and Highcharts events and API methods. It takes a
standard Highcharts config with a small variation for each data set, and a
mouse/touch event handler to bind the charts together.
*/



/**
 * In order to synchronize tooltips and crosshairs, override the
 * built-in events with handlers defined on the parent element.
 */
$('#container').bind('mousemove touchmove touchstart', function (e) {
    var chart,
        point,
        i,
        event;

    for (i = 0; i < Highcharts.charts.length; i = i + 1) {
        chart = Highcharts.charts[i];
        // Find coordinates within the chart
        event = chart.pointer.normalize(e.originalEvent);
        // Get the hovered point
        point = chart.series[0].searchPoint(event, true);

        if (point) {
            point.highlight(e);
        }
    }
});
/**
 * Override the reset function, we don't need to hide the tooltips and
 * crosshairs.
 */
Highcharts.Pointer.prototype.reset = function () {
    return undefined;
};

/**
 * Highlight a point by showing tooltip, setting hover state and draw crosshair
 */
Highcharts.Point.prototype.highlight = function (event) {
    event = this.series.chart.pointer.normalize(event);
    this.onMouseOver(); // Show the hover marker
    this.series.chart.tooltip.refresh(this); // Show the tooltip
    this.series.chart.xAxis[0].drawCrosshair(event, this); // Show the crosshair
};

/**
 * Synchronize zooming through the setExtremes event handler.
 */
function syncExtremes(e) {
    var thisChart = this.chart;

    if (e.trigger !== 'syncExtremes') { // Prevent feedback loop
        Highcharts.each(Highcharts.charts, function (chart) {
            if (chart !== thisChart) {
                if (chart.xAxis[0].setExtremes) { // It is null while updating
                    chart.xAxis[0].setExtremes(
                        e.min,
                        e.max,
                        undefined,
                        false,
                        { trigger: 'syncExtremes' }
                    );
                }
            }
        });
    }
}

// Get the data. The contents of the data file can be viewed at
$.getJSON(
    'https://cdn.rawgit.com/highcharts/highcharts/057b672172ccc6c08fe7dbb27fc17ebca3f5b770/samples/data/activity.json',
    function (activity) {
        $.each(activity.datasets, function (i, dataset) {

            // Add X values
            dataset.data = Highcharts.map(dataset.data, function (val, j) {
                return [activity.xData[j], val];
            });

            $('<div class="chart">')
                .appendTo('#container')
                .highcharts({
                    chart: {
                        marginLeft: 40, // Keep all charts left aligned
                        spacingTop: 20,
                        spacingBottom: 20
                    },
                    title: {
                        text: dataset.name,
                        align: 'left',
                        margin: 0,
                        x: 30
                    },
                    credits: {
                        enabled: false
                    },
                    legend: {
                        enabled: false
                    },
                    xAxis: {
                        crosshair: true,
                        events: {
                            setExtremes: syncExtremes
                        },
                        labels: {
                            format: '{value} min'
                        }
                    },
                    yAxis: {
                        title: {
                            text: null
                        }
                    },
                    tooltip: {
                        positioner: function () {
                            return {
                                // right aligned
                                x: this.chart.chartWidth - this.label.width,
                                y: 10 // align to title
                            };
                        },
                        borderWidth: 0,
                        backgroundColor: 'none',
                        pointFormat: '{point.y}',
                        headerFormat: '',
                        shadow: false,
                        style: {
                            fontSize: '18px'
                        },
                        valueDecimals: dataset.valueDecimals
                    },
                    series: [{
                        data: dataset.data,
                        name: dataset.name,
                        type: dataset.type,
                        color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[i],
                        fillOpacity: 0.3,
                        tooltip: {
                            valueSuffix: ' ' + dataset.unit
                        }
                    }]
                });
        });
    }
);
```

```css
.chart {
    min-width: 320px;
    max-width: 800px;
    height: 220px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
</style>
<!-- http://doc.jsfiddle.net/use/hacks.html#css-panel-hack -->
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
<style>
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>

<div id="container"></div>
```